# Testing if a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript

I know the answer is probably staring me in the face, but how do I find out if a checkbox is checked or not?

```
var sa = document.getElementById("sa").checked;
var test = function () {
    if (sa) {}
    alert("true");
} else {}
alert("false");
}

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
    test();
}, false);
```

Comment: Don't store the checkedness state in a global variable, but read the value whenever it's clicked: `if (document.getElementById("sa").checked) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you are not checking on runtime if the checkbox is checked. You do it at page load, and thats it.

You need to modify your code to:

```
var test = function () {
    if (document.getElementById("sa").checked) {
        alert("true");
    }
    else {
        alert("false");
    }
}

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
    test();
}, false);
```